# How to control PulseEffects volume with keyboard?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Since I installed PulseEffects, the built-in volume control does not work.
How can I control the volume with keyboard on PulseEffects?

Details:

- Also read that could be a Pulseaudio 11 bug, I have upgraded to 12.2 and the issue remains.
- When I press the volume control buttons, it shows "PulseEffects(mic)" it may even be trying to change volume of the mic instead of the speakers?

I have Ubuntu 18.04, Pulseaudio 12.2, PulseEffects 4.7.0 (installed with Flatpak)

Edit:

1. I tried setting Settings -> Sound -> PuleEffects(apps) but with this setting it just disabled all sound.
2. Found a solution, see below.

Comment: How do you change volume now? Eg GUI, command line or both.

Comment: I changed it with media control hotkeys of my keyboard (volume +/-) until it worked. Now even adjusting the built-in volume bar with mouse clicks doesn't work. Only adjusting inside the PulseEffects application works.

Comment: This will give you an idea of how to debug a problem in PulseEffects: https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects/issues/99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it (thanks for the comments too):

- Reverted to Pulseaudio 11.1 (it's the default which comes with Ubuntu 18.04)
- Installed PulsEffects from this PPA (instead of Flatpak, this PPA installs 4.7.1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mikhailnov/pulseeffects -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pulseeffects
```

Went to **Settings** -> **Sound** and selected **PuleEffects(apps)** as Output:
[image]

And now the volume control and media hotkeys work with PulseEffects.